# Laravel many to many relastionship count

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables. User and days, with many to many relationship.
user_days : user_id, day_id

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_day');
}

public function days()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Day::class, 'user_day');
}
```

I want to get the count number of users in day_id = 1 {for a particular day} or something like this. Any way to get count from pivot table?
This function didnot work.

```
public function assign_prize(Request $request)
{
    $userCount = $this->user->days()->withCount('users')->where($request->day_id, 'day_id')->get();
    $giftLimit = Day::where('id', $request->day_id)->get();
    if ($userCount > $giftLimit) {
        return problem(__("Gift for the current day has been finished!!"), 500, "Gift Assign Failed");
    }
```

the table structure ?

```
Schema::create('user_day', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('day_id')->unsigned();
    $table->boolean('assigned')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

How do I find the user count of users on that particular day??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the count of users related to that day.

```
public function assign_prize(Request $request)
{
   
   $day = Day::withCount('users')->find($request->day_id);

   if ($day->users_count > $day->gift_limit) {
       return problem(__("Gift for the current day has been finished!!"), 500, "Gift Assign Failed");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the count selector at the end of your eloquent request :

```php
$userCount = users::all()->count();
```

Comment: btw, you probably wouldn't want to pull all the records from the database (`all`)[ returns a collection of models ] to then just count them ... you can have the database return the count by calling `count` on the builder itself (call `count` instead of `all`)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this:

```
$dayId = $request->day_id;

// Get the count of users from the chosen day id
$userCount = User::where('day_id', '=', $dayId)->count();

// Set the limit and make a validation
$dayLimit = 5
   if ($userCount > $dayLimit) {
    dd('Limit exceeded');
   }
   else {
    dd('Within limit');
   }
```

Edit: As suggested, you can create a `UserLog` model and migration to make easier queries later on. See sample code below:

```
$dayId = $request->day_id;

// Get today's date

   $timeStamp = Carbon::now()->format("h:i A");

// Check first if there's an existing log

  $findIfThereIsLog = UserLog::where('user_id', '=', Auth::User()->id)
  ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today()->startOfDay())
  ->first();

// Proceed with the logging if there's none

   if ($findIfThereIsLog === null) {

    $newUserLog = new UserLog;

    $newUserLog->user_id = Auth::User()->id;
    $newUserLog->day_id = $dayId;
    $newUserLog->save();

  }

  else {

    // Do nothing

  }
```

From there you can easily do queries like:

```
// Get the number of users from a particular day id

$dayId = $request->day_id;

$getUserFromDayId = UserLog::where('day_id', '=', $dayId)->count();
```

Comment: day_id is in user_day table not is users table. I need to count from pivot table?? @miguban

Comment: If this is the case, I believe it's better to create a UserLog model and migration where both user_id and day_id columns are foreign keys. Presuming users cannot have multiple records of the same day_id, you just have to create a validation to make sure that your app records users only once per day_id. I'll edit my answer to show you an example.

Comment: I already did that. Here I only need the no of users in day_id=2. I need to get count of users. I have user_day pivot table. Any way to do this??Might be my mistake, I havent written qn correctly. I have updated the qn

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it helps.